# Warning: NUMERIC_STD."<=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE Error in Modelmsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am getting the following error : Warning: NUMERIC_STD."<=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE, in Modelsim when I run my code.

The error only happens when i am using reg_go and reg_n registers. If do not use the registers, the code works fine.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.config_pkg.all;
use work.user_pkg.all;

entity memory_map is
port (
    clk     : in  std_logic;
    rst     : in  std_logic;
    wr_en   : in  std_logic;
    wr_addr : in  std_logic_vector(MMAP_ADDR_RANGE);
    wr_data : in  std_logic_vector(MMAP_DATA_RANGE);
    rd_en   : in  std_logic;
    rd_addr : in  std_logic_vector(MMAP_ADDR_RANGE);
    rd_data : out std_logic_vector(MMAP_DATA_RANGE);

    -- application-specific I/O
    go     : out std_logic;
    n      : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    result : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    done   : in  std_logic
    );
end memory_map;

architecture BHV of memory_map is
signal reg_go, reg_go1     :  std_logic;
signal reg_n      :  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin

process(clk,rst)

begin


    if(rst = '1') then
        reg_go <= '0';
        reg_go <= '0';
        reg_n <= (others => '0');
        rd_data <= (others => '0');

    elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then

        if(wr_en='1') then

            if(wr_addr=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(C_GO_ADDR,C_MMAP_ADDR_WIDTH))) then

                    reg_go <= wr_data(0);
                    reg_go1 <= '1';

            elsif(wr_addr=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(C_N_ADDR,C_MMAP_ADDR_WIDTH))) then
                    reg_n <=wr_data;


            end if;
        end if;

        reg_go1 <= '0';

        if(rd_en='1') then
            if(rd_addr=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( C_RESULT_ADDR,C_MMAP_ADDR_WIDTH))) then
                rd_data <= result;
            elsif(rd_addr=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(C_DONE_ADDR,C_MMAP_ADDR_WIDTH))) then

                rd_data(0) <= done;

            end if;
        end if;
    end if;

end process;



go <= reg_go and reg_go1;
n  <= reg_n;





end BHV;
```

Comment: Since when is a warning an error? You're code example isn't a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the warning messages can't be duplicated missing declarations for MMAP_ADDR_RANGE, MMAP_DATA_RANGE, C_GO_ADDR, C_MMAP_ADDR_WIDTH, C_N_ADDR, C_RESULT_ADDR and C_DONE_ADDR (presumably from either package config_pkg and/or user_pkg). Further your warning is from function "<="  which isn't used in the code you've chosen to share. (You'd expect 'less than or equal to' to show up in a condition). Something's not initialized to a known value somewhere.

Comment: error as in when I simulate it, its completely wrong. As i mentioned in the brief, the error is because of the reg_n and reg_go. I removed them and tested the code and it worked just fine. Thank you for your input

Comment: Notice ouputs go and n depend on reg_n and reg_go. Where are they used? You're simply not using a numeric_std  "<=" operator in the code you've shown.

Comment: reg_n has no initial value provided in it's declaration. reg_n will have an initial value of all 'U's. If you are using it in a comparison elsewhere with a numeric_std."<=" operator presumably after converting it to a signed or unsigned you will get the warning.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find a compare `<=` for `reg_go` or `reg_n` in the provided code that I would suspect giving the warning "NUMERIC_STD."<=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE".

However, a meta value is those extra values in `std_logic` that does not represent `'0'` and `'1'`, like for example `'X'`.  So what the warning means is that there is a compare `<=` where one of the arguments contains for example `'X'` or `'U'`, whereby a meaningful compare cant be made, and the function thus returns `FALSE`.

Take a look in the simulator at the time where the warning is reported, and check the value of the relevant arguments, check the value of the arguments.